# arrow key problem with vnc server in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vnc

I installed vnc4server on Ubnutu 18.04 and I installed vncviewer on Windows 7. After I logged into the vnc4server on Ubuntu, everything works well. However, in the terminal, the arrow keys do not work properly. When I press left, right and up arrow keys, it does not respond at all. When I press the down arrow key, it works like the "Enter" key. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Gnome does not work well with vncserver, so I use xfce4.

Answer (score 1):

This is a workable xstartup file:

!/bin/bash

export XKB_DEFAULT_RULES=base

export SESSION_MANAGER=

export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=

startxfce4 &

Here, "export XKB_DEFAULT_RULES=base" solves the arrow key problem.